# После сборки приложение не запускается с адреса, отличного от корневого

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

После сборки приложения, если в продакшене открыть сайт в корне, то все будет нормально. При перемещении по сайту все отлично.

Вот как выглядит source:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я попытаюсь перейти к URL-адресу, отличному от корневого, например `/profile`, то react просто сломается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На экране ничего не отображается и source странный.

Я создал приложение, используя `create-react-app`.

Вот как я отправляю приложение с сервера:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', "build")));

    app.get('*',
        async(req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
        }
    );
}
```

ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// Pages
import Main from './Pages/Main/Main';
import Auth from './Pages/Auth/Auth';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile/Profile';
import Blog from './Pages/Blog/Blog';
import CreateBlog from './Pages/CreateBlog/CreateBlog';
import PostPage from './Pages/PostPage/PostPage';
import BlogsAndUsers from './Pages/BlogsAndUsers/BlogsAndUsers';

// Components
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="notification-bar"></div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact>
                    <Main />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/auth' exact>
                    <Auth />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/blog/:id' exact>
                    <Blog />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/blogs' exact>
                    <BlogsAndUsers type="blogs" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/profiles' exact>
                    <BlogsAndUsers type="profiles" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/create_blog' exact>
                    <CreateBlog />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/profile/:id" exact>
                    <Profile />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/article/:id" exact>
                    <PostPage />
                </Route>
                <Redirect to='/' />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import './fonts/fonts-import.css'

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Простите за низкое разрешение.

Comment: у тебя в html, в подключении скриптов-стилей, относительные ссылки стоят. т.е. берёшь ты `/profile/aaa`, отличный от `index.html`, с сервача отдаёшь на него 'index.html', а в нём написано `<link href="app.js">` или `<link href="./app.js">`. браузер запрашивает у сервера `/profile/app.js`, а твой экспресовский сервачок роутит запрос в '*' и отдаёт 'index.html'

Comment: короче, сделай сборку, в которой не будет относительных урлов. беглый гуглёж даёт как минимум 2 способа: `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` и https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths. и ответ потом напиши

Comment: @nörbörnën, изменил homepage с `./` на `http://localhost:5500` и все заработало

Comment: а как ты поступишь при раскатке на настоящем prodcution?

Comment: @nörbörnën, перепишу поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я заменил `"homepage": "./"` на `"homepage": "http://localhost:5500"` и все заработало.